Does a 16-valence 192-edge Graceful Graph exist?
In Knuth's fascicle 7A, exercise 93, he lists Graceful Graphs for Valence k and mentions the conjecture that the minimal graceful graphs with valence $2n$ have $3n^2$ edges. (This will be removed from the printed version) Here's valence 6:

If it's true for valence 16, then the graceful graph will have one of two sets of vertices.
{{0,1,3,5,7,9,18,27,36,52,68,84,100,116,132,148,164,171,178,185,186,188,190,192},{0,1,3,6,7,13,19,25,40,55,70,85,100,115,130,145,156,160,165,174,183,188,191,192}}
I haven't figure out a good way to boil down the cases, so I'll toss it here. Can either of these two vertex sets produce a 16-valence graceful graph?
I may as well toss in the 14-valence case as well, which would use one of these five sets of vertices:
{{0,1,2,6,10,11,12,68,76,78,86,93,100,107,114,121,128,135,141,144,147},{0,1,2,4,6,11,17,22,36,50,64,78,92,106,120,123,132,135,143,144,147},{0,1,3,9,15,23,24,37,50,63,76,89,102,115,128,133,135,140,144,145,147},{0,1,2,3,6,11,12,68,69,77,86,93,100,107,114,121,128,135,141,143,147},{0,1,3,6,7,13,19,25,40,55,70,85,100,111,115,120,129,138,143,146,147}}
I haven't been able to make a 14-valence, 147 edge graph from one of these.
Edit: I may as well add the only known sparse ruler of length 243. There may be other sparse rulers for this length. This could possibly make an 18-valence graceful graph.
{0,1,2,3,7,14,21,28,43,58,73,88,103,118,133,148,163,178,193,208,216,224,232,240,241,242,243}
